# How do I install php with sqlite support in AWS EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, sqlite

I'm trying to run an AWS EC2 instance for a facebook app.  I chose the micro Amazon linux 32-bit as my OS.  I'm able to SSH in and install PHP with yum, but when I run phpinfo() I see --without-sqlite in the configuration.  Also, my sqlite php page was erroring out on the line that tried to open the sqlite file.  I did a yum search for sqlite and php and I didn't see the php5-sqlite pacakge available.  How can I get SQLite working with PHP on this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to use SQLite3, even if your install of PHP doesn't have native SQLite support compiled in.

You can install the PDO library with:

`yum install php-pdo`

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  For anyone else that finds this question, I found the PDO tutorial on PHPRO helpful. [http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.2](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.2)